# Filtrar direcciones MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos con direcciones. El nombre de la calle **no incluye** el tipo de vía (ej. "Calle" o "Avenida").

La consulta para filtrar los resultados es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}cobertura
WHERE Calle LIKE '%$_GET[Calle]%'
AND NUMERO LIKE '$_GET[NUMERO]'
AND Provincia LIKE '$_GET[Provincia]'
AND TIPO != 'null'
```

Ahora, si en el formulario de búsqueda yo pongo "Holanda", me filtra los resultados correctamente, lo mismo que si pongo "land".

La cuestión es que si un usuario intenta filtrar, por ejemplo, por "Calle Holanda", no devuelve resultados ya que la palabra "Calle" no existe en la columna.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que lo filtre, obviando las palabras que no están en el registro?

Comment: Está complicado porque es el usuario el que específicamente pone eso. Se me ocurre que hagas una lista de tipos de vía, lo metas en un array, y hagas un `string_replace` por una cadena vacía o similares. Pero en cualquier caso, debemos tender a la normalización, y si el usuario no atiende a eso... Es un poco su problema. Especialmente, si se avisa en la aplicación con un mensaje de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ponerlo de esta manera: WHERE concat(‘%’,Calle) LIKE '%$_GET[Calle]%'

Si no te funciona así intenta modificar el final del like, ponle comodín al inicio, quítaselo, igual al final, comodín al final o no y así…